What is this C14-like DC connector?
I'm building a solar charger for my electric motorbike. The charger connector looks like an IEC 60320 C14, but it's actually smaller.

That's a C14 connector on the left, and the connector on the right is for the charger. On the top of the connector is written "+ DC 100V 6A -". Any ideas what the connector on the right is?

It looks like it might be a non-standard reverse-polarity C13. A standard C13 connector looks like this:

(image source: product listing on walmart.com)
Yours appears to have the same external dimensions (you can check this by seeing if the outer shell fits into that C14 connector there) and pin pitch as this, but with pins where the C13 has sockets. Presumably, your connector would mate with a similarly nonstandard reverse-polarity C14, with sockets where standard C14 has pins. As this is a nonstandard connector, I'm afraid I have no idea where you might find one, or if it even has a name.

You are right that the charger connector fits exactly inside the C14 connector (though not very far in because the pin polarities conflict) however the pin spacing is different- 15mm vs 13mm between the live and neutral pins.
